# Laravel 5.4 Nginx 1.10 PHP 7 route except "/" are returning 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

This is my config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.com;

    root /var/www/site/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files \$uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The root of my site is accessible, all other routes are returning a 404 error.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the difference is, but I deleted the config file and made a copy of the default config, made changes to the lines I needed to. (i.e. server_name, root)

And it started working.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes ... I run php 7.1 ...

location... try /index.php?$query_string; as in the example below...

```
server {
    listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name mysite.com;

root /var/www/site/public;
index index.php index.html;



index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }



    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `PHP-FPM` runs same user as `nginx`
i.e. `sudo vim /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
...
user = nginx
group = nginx
...
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
...
```

Then `sudo systemctl restart php7.1-fpm.service`

This is my configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/user/projects/apple/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name apple.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```